# NumberLong in Mongo shell

Tags: shell, mongodb

Is there any way how to use long integer data type in Mongo shell?

```
db.users_stats.find().forEach(function(row) {
    var newRow = row;
    newRow.user_id = new NumberLong(row.user_id);
    newRow.date = new Date(row.date);
    printjson(newRow);
});

JS Error: TypeError: NumberLong is not a constructor mongoConvert.js:3



db.users_stats.find().forEach(function(row) {
    var newRow = row;
    newRow.app_id = NumberLong(row.user_id);
    newRow.date = new Date(row.date);
    printjson(newRow);
});

JS Error: TypeError: NumberLong is not a function mongoConvert.js:3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should work fine. The errors you're seeing are wicked, I can't reproduce them. Which version are you using? In `1.8.1`, I can't reproduce the "`NumberLong` is not a constructor" error.

The following works for me:

```
db.Test.find().forEach(function(row) {
    var newRow = row;
    if(typeof row.myId == 'number')
        newRow.user_id = new NumberLong(row.myId);
    else if(row.myId instanceof NumberLong)
        newRow.user_id = row.myId;
    printjson(newRow);
});
```